# Unhandled event loop exception : On attempt to import project

Tags: eclipse

I am running eclipse 2020-06 downloaded [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2020-06/R/eclipse-cpp-2020-06-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)

It's being installed in VM at opt
Everytime I try importing a project/browse/ open any local directory, there will be Unhandled event loop exception.

Log:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4749)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4638)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4609)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Dialog.error(Dialog.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DirectoryDialog.openNativeChooserDialog(DirectoryDialog.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DirectoryDialog.open(DirectoryDialog.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.CreateLinkedResourceGroup.handleLinkTargetBrowseButtonPressed(CreateLinkedResourceGroup.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.CreateLinkedResourceGroup.access$0(CreateLinkedResourceGroup.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.CreateLinkedResourceGroup$2.widgetSelected(CreateLinkedResourceGroup.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5685)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1423)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4953)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4446)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5685)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1423)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4953)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4446)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1420)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't use the C++ tag for questions that aren't related to C++. Eclipse is a Java application so there's a better chance Java programmers might help you. Also note that your question looks like it is not so much about some code you're writing but more about a potential bug in a tool. It might make more sense to file a bug report with the Eclipse project.

Comment: I'm confused: The link you're posting points to a Linux version but you are talking about Windows. On which OS is Eclipse running?

Comment: It's running on Linux in a Virtual Machine. I've updated the question to avoid confusion.